# one list object does not support indexing, but the other one does?

Tags: python, list, object, indexing

I am new to Stack overflow and am writing this program in python, which should create two different game board objects: a small one and a big one. Both game board objects are made out of lists, so I can later access specific spaces on the boards through indexes. There aren't any apparent errors with the bigger one of the boards, but when I create small board objects and try to access their specific spaces through indexes I get the error 'object does not support indexing.' I am really confused, as it worked with the big board and I already went through loads of other posts about this error, but they all seem to find the mistake in the object not being an actual list. However I define in the constructor, that it should be a list. I hope you guys can help!

Here's the code for the classes:

```
import copy

SMALL_BOARD = [ #one list for small board
      None, None, None,
      None, None, None,
      None, None, None,
]

BIG_BOARD = [ #one big list for big board
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None,
 ]

class SMALLBoard():
      def __init__(self, board=None):
          if board is None:
              board = copy.deepcopy(SMALL_BOARD)
          self.sboard = board

class BIGBoard():
    def __init__(self, bboard=None):
        if bboard is None:
            bboard = copy.deepcopy(BIG_BOARD)
        self.bboard = bboard 

    def equal_small_boards(self, boardA, boardB, boardC, boardD):
        tempboard=BIGBoard()
        tempboard[0]= boardA[0]
        tempboard[3]= boardB[0]
        tempboard[18]= boardC[0]
        tempboard[21]= boardD[0]

        return tempboard
```

When I ran the following code I got the error: 'in equal_small_boards
    tempboard[0]= boardA[0]
TypeError: 'SMALLBoard' object does not support indexing'

```
 bboard = BIGBoard()
sboardA = SMALLBoard()
sboardB = SMALLBoard()
sboardC = SMALLBoard()
sboardD = SMALLBoard()

bboard=bboard.equal_small_boards(sboardA, sboardB, sboardC, sboardD)
```

Thanks for your answers in advance! :)

Comment: `tempboard` is a a `BIGBoard`, and `BIGBoard`s do not support indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem occurs on your method:

```
def equal_small_boards(self, boardA, boardB, boardC, boardD):
    tempboard=BIGBoard()
    tempboard[0]= boardA[0]
    tempboard[3]= boardB[0]
    tempboard[18]= boardC[0]
    tempboard[21]= boardD[0]

    return tempboard
```

`tempboard` is a `BIGBoard`, and the `BIGBoard` does not support indexing. You probably want to write to its `bboard` field. So:

```
def equal_small_boards(self, boardA, boardB, boardC, boardD):
    tempboard = BIGBoard()
    tempboard.bboard[0] = boardA[0]
    tempboard.bboard[3] = boardB[0]
    tempboard.bboard[18] = boardC[0]
    tempboard.bboard[21] = boardD[0]

    return tempboard
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, although I also needed to add the specific fields for boardA, boardB, boardC and boardD to get the program to run without error.